# Problem with creating table on phpMyAdmin database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm running a phpMyAdmin Database on my web package on a 1and1-hosted server. I've managed to set up a database in the control panel, have uploaded all to root/phpmyadmin and changed the config.ini.php file to point at 1and1's database server (because that's the way they do it). I can go to the web interface and get to the main page, but all it shows is the database name and I can't find how to create any tables. I know it's a long shot but I'm almost out of ideas.

Also, 1and1 have their own phpmyadmin panel, which is pretty annoying to use, and a 1and1 webdatabase which I have barely looked at.

Help and suggestions much appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check on the 1and1 control panel if the user has enough privileges on the database. Often users are created with just "USAGE" privileges, so they cannot create/modify/delete tables.

Comment: coming back to it, this was the answer in the end.